# Python: k-means clustering on multiple variables from a predetermined csv

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm working at a project for my thesis but I'm very sad because I can't do the k-means clustering on my dataset from Spotify API.

> artist_name   track_popularity    explicit    artist_genres   album_genres    acousticness    danceability    energy  instrumentalness    key     liveness    loudness    mode    speechness  tempo   time_signature  valence     played_at

My dataset has these variables, I have to make clustering on the variables from acoustincness to valence (so 12 variables). How can I do this?
I can do this with 2 or 3 variables, but I can't do it with four o more than four variables.

```
> from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
#importing Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('csvProva2.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [10,11]].values #colonne che mi interessano

#Find the number of clusters
wcss = []

for i in range (1,16): #15 cluster
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init='k-means++', random_state=0) 
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plot.plot(range(1,16),wcss)
plot.title('Elbow Method')
plot.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plot.ylabel('wcss')
plot.show()

#KMeans clustering
kmeans= KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++', random_state=0)
y=kmeans.fit_predict(X)

plot.scatter(X[y == 0,0], X[y==0,1], s=25, c='red', label='Cluster 1')
plot.scatter(X[y == 1,0], X[y==1,1], s=25, c='blue', label='Cluster 2')
plot.scatter(X[y == 2,0], X[y==2,1], s=25, c='magenta', label='Cluster 3')
plot.scatter(X[y == 3,0], X[y==3,1], s=25, c='cyan', label='Cluster 4')

plot.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], s=25, c='yellow', label='Centroid')
plot.title('KMeans Clustering')
plot.xlabel('Acousticness')
plot.ylabel('Danceability')
plot.legend()
plot.show()
```

Here it's my code for clustering with 2 variables.

Comment: I have solved here: https://github.com/joaocarvalhoopen/Excel_table_clustering_using_K-Means_ML/blob/master/Excel_table_clustering_code_using_K-Means_in_Python.ipynb

Answer (score 3):

K-means will run just fine on more than 3 variables.

*But* they need to be continuous variables. You *cannot* compute the mean of a categoricial variable. Also, mixing variables with different scakes (units) is problematic. The small scale features then will be mostly ignored. Statiatically, the results become quite meaningless: if you scaled the data differently, you would get a different result.

Comment: What to do when the dataset have NaN values in some columns?

Comment: Is it best practice to standardise all variables/features to one scale, e.g. from 0 to 1?